# Как сохранять массив GameObject-ов

Tags: unity3d

Как сохранить и загрузить `GameObject[]` в Unity?
Пробовал через `PlayerPrefs`, но он работает через раз..

Comment: Что значит "сохранить"?? Какой именно жц вы имеете в виду? Вы хотите выключить игру, а потом включить и загрузить, или просто на одной сцене сохранить а на другой загрузить?

Answer (score 2):

Лучший способ сохранения не только `GameObject`-ов, но и всего остального это использовать`PlayerPrefs` и `JsonUtility` вместе.

## Сохранение

Для сохранения в `PlayerPrefs` нужно писать так:

```cs
PlayerPrefs.SetString(string keyName, string objectToSave);
```

... где `keyName` это название ключа, а `objetcToSave` это на данном случае строковое поле которое мы хотим сохранить. Ключ это слово которое вы сами должны придумать и под этим названием будет сохраниться переменная.

А в `JsonUtility` сохраняем вот так:

```cs
string keyName = JsonUtility.ToJson(object objectToSave);
```

Ключ тут создаётся автоматически, при чём объект который вы хотите сохранить кодируется под строку (это и есть сам ключ).

Если их соединить получаем более качественный и удобный способ сохранения.

```cs
PlayerPrefs.SetString(string keyName, JsonUtility.ToJson(object objectToSave));
```

Тут вместо строки передаём зашифрованный ключ. Так сказать сохраняем ключ в ключе. В итоге у нас получается так:

```cs
private GameObject[] GameObjects;

public void Save()
{
    PlayerPrefs.SetString("SecretKey007" ,JsonUtility.ToJson(GameObjects));
}
```

---

## Загрузка

Вы наверно думали зачем все эти ключи. Чтобы восстановить переменную - я скажу вам.
В `PlayerPrefs` это выглядит так:

```cs
string objectToLoad = PlayerPrefs.GetString(string keyName);
```

В `JsonUtility` загрузка почти не отличается от `PlayerPrefs` только там надо определить тип объекта. То есть:

```cs
T objectToLoad = JsonUtility.FromJson<T>(string keyName);
```

Где `T` это тип - `int`, `bool`, `object`, `Vector2`, `GameObject[]` и так далее.
Теперь соединяем:

```cs
private GameObject[] GameObjects;

public void Load()
{
    GameObjects = JsonUtility.FromJson<GameObject[]>(PlayePrefs.GetString("SecretKey007"));
}
```

## Полный скрипт

Полный скрипт будет у нас таким:

```cs
private GameObject[] GameObjects;

public void Save()
{
    PlayerPrefs.SetString("SecretKey007" ,JsonUtility.ToJson(GameObjects));
}

public void Load()
{
    GameObjects = JsonUtility.FromJson<GameObject[]>(PlayePrefs.GetString("SecretKey007"));
}
```

Для дальнейшего сохранения и загрузки используем функции `Save` и `Load`. Например:

```cs
private void OnApplicationPause(bool isPaused)
{
    if(isPaused)
    {
        Save();
    }
    else
    {
        Load();
    }
}
```